# Subtract List B from List A, but keeping the List A index and using difflib string similarity

Tags: python, string, match, subtraction, difflib

I need some help with Python. This is not the classic subtract List B from List A to make List C. Instead I would like to look at the indexes of the items in List A (city names in a single word) that are not in List B, and store them into a new List C. Also, matched items in List B are not exactly the same that the ones in List A, they come from OCR, so they are little misspelled, I would like to consider a match if they are 90% similar.

e.g.

List A: #all list items are citynames in just a single word

```
0. Corneria
1. klandasco
2. Blue_Mars
3. Setiro
4. Jeti_lo
5. Neo_Tokyo
```

List B: #citynames are little misspelled

```
0. lcandasco
1. Ne0_Tolcyo
```

So, the result should be...

List C:

```
[0, 2, 3, 4]
```

The result items are not important (Corneria, Blue_Mars, Setiro, Jeti_lo), instead I need to keep the original indexes of the items in List A, once the subtraction has been made.

So far Im doing this...

```
a = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "ccc", "eee"]
b = ["bbb", "eee"]
c = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) if v not in b]
print(c)
```

output...

```
[0, 2, 3, 4]
```

But I need to implement the difflib part in order to match items with 90% of similarity, how could I do this using only pure python script, (preferibly using only difflib)???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

max_ratio = 0.9

c = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) 
     if not any(map(lambda x: SequenceMatcher(None, v, x).ratio()>=max_ratio, b))]
```

Snippet which used `fuzzywuzzy`:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

max_ratio = 90

c = [i for i, v in enumerate(a) 
     if not any(map(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(v, x)>=max_ratio, b))]
```

Note. Before using `fuzzywuzzy` you should install it.

Comment: Thanks Alex Lisovoy, worked like a charm. Hope Im not abussing, but, how the script would look like if I would need to use fuzzywuzzy matching instead? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: I added snippet with `fuzzywuzzy` lib